# Calling 2 different views in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 versions of the same pages in my rails app and I would like for them to alternately load when the same page is called.

So for example: On page load index view comes up. On reload or refresh the alt_index page loads. How can I accomplish this? I am sure it can be accomplished in a controller action but not sure how.

```
class ComingSoonController < ApplicationController
 def index
   render('alt_index' || 'index')
 end

end
```

This only renders the alt_index page I need it to alternate.

Comment: Alternate per person/session or per view or perhaps a random one and hope the probability distribution looks close enough to alternating not to matter?

Comment: I would prefer alternating per view

Comment: `%w[alt_index index].sample` like infused suggests would be easiest and would roughly cycle between the versions. Otherwise you'd have to store some state somewhere so that the controller could know which one it showed last time.

Comment: I figured as much. Storing the state is too much for this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you randomly select one of the templates to render with Array#sample instead of trying to alternate between them:

```
render ['alt_index', 'index'].sample
```